# Como adicionar métodos a uma QuerySet?

Tags: python, query, django

Eu tenho um model definido no Django. Eu gostaria de adicionar a esse model um método que me retorne parte de uma query montada (uma [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/)). 
Ou seja, um método quero definir um método que afete os resultados da consulta ao chamar `Model.objects`. A minha intenção ao fazer isso é melhorar o reaproveitamento, evitando a repetição constante de queries complexas.

Exemplo:

```
class Empresas(models.Model):
    nome_fantasia = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    logradouro = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=19)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


def metodo_especial_com_uma_query_padrao_especifica(self):
     pass
```

Como fazer isso no Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode estender o **Model Manager** e adicionar um método de **QuerySet** customizado. Veja um exemplo abaixo onde adicionei um filtro para empresas localizadas no Sudeste e para empresas PME:

```
class EmpresaQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def sudeste(self):
        return self.filter(uf__in=['ES', 'MG', 'SP', 'RJ'])

    def pme(self):
        '''Pequena e média empresa'''
        return self.filter(tipo='PME')

class Empresa(models.Model):
    nome_fantasia = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    logradouro = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=455, blank=True, null=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=19)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    objects = EmpresaQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Com isso você pode executar *queries* desta forma:

```
empresas = Empresa.objects.sudeste().order_by('nome_fantasia')
```

Ou intercalar os filtros:

```
empresas = Empresa.objects.pme().sudeste().filter(nome_fantasia__startswith='G')
```

Mais detalhes na [documentação oficial do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/).